# how to create a function that executes other functions inside of it

Tags: c++, function

I have created a battleship game, and I have successfully created all the functions for the game properly. To give myself a bit more of a challenge, i wanted to create a function that would execute everything that I have written in my main function in another function that would be the only one invoked in the main function. So instead of calling all of these other functions, I would only like to call one in the main function.

I have tried to create a void function to tackle this problem, but it seems to not be working for me. this code below that i have posted is my main function, while Ship and Location are the two classes i was working with in this project.

```
Ship myFleet[fleetSize];
std::string print;

srand(int(time(0)));

initialize(myFleet);
deploy(myFleet);

cout << "print fleet? y/n: ";
cin >> print;
if (print == "y" )
    printFleet(myFleet);

while (operational(myFleet))
{
    Location myLocation = fire();
    int index = check(myFleet, myLocation);
    if (index != -1)
    {
        sink(myFleet[index]);
        cout << "It's a HIT !" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "It's a MISS!" << endl;
    }

}

cout << "Game over !" << endl;
}
```

I am expecting to get all of this information into a single function to be run inside the main function but I cannot figure this out. I would appreciate the help from the stackoverflow community.

Comment: "*I have tried to create a void function*" - I see no declarations of any function in the code you shared.

Comment: initialize, deploy, operational,check, printfleet, and sink are all functions i have declared. i just did not include the definitions since i do not think they are needed at this time.

Comment: "but it seems to not be working for me" Could you clarify what you mean by that? Do you get a compiler error? If you do, could you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58600271/edit) and copy and paste the error and the code used to create the error in?

Comment: alright, I have edited my question

Comment: Are you having trouble copying your `main` function into another (`void`?) function?

Comment: YES jason, that's exactly the problem im having. i want the contents of the main function to be inside a void function, and i want to call only this newly created function inside of the main function.

Comment: @mooha Where specifically are you having difficulty?  Declaring a `void` function?  Copying `main` to the `void` function?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to have something like this:

```cpp
void myFunc()
{
    Ship myFleet[fleetSize];
    std::string print;

    srand(int(time(0)));

    initialize(myFleet);
    deploy(myFleet);

    cout << "print fleet? y/n: ";
    cin >> print;
    if (print == "y" )
        printFleet(myFleet);

    while (operational(myFleet))
    {
        Location myLocation = fire();
        int index = check(myFleet, myLocation);
        if (index != -1)
        {
            sink(myFleet[index]);
            cout << "It's a HIT !" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "It's a MISS!" << endl;
        }

    }

    cout << "Game over !" << endl;
}

int main(char argc, char ** argv)
{
    myFunc();
    return 0;
}
```

Or maybe I couldn't understand what are you trying to do.